# Flutter - FCM , Is there a way to refresh the app when the notification arrives on foreground state of the app?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-layout, local

[ Note :- I've used local notification to display the notification when the app is in the foreground state but I want to refresh the app on it's arrival.]

I want to refresh the app when it detects the notification.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
  showNotification(message.notification.title, message.notification.body,
      message.data["logic_flow"]);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh the app"? Reload the current page? Restart the app completely as if the app was just launched?

Comment: Restart the app completely as if the app was just launched.